# How to reset the page number back to 1 at every subsection part 2

Tags: page-numbering

I recently asked the same question:

- [How to reset the page number back to 1 at every subsection?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/351985/2693)

and it worked halfway, but it also changed something in my other codes. What I want is to simply have the page number reset to 1 at every subsection (i.e., 1.1, 1.2, etc). User @user124577 helped me a lot, but his help led to the ignoring of the `\MakeUpperCase` command and to the displacement of the Section 1.1 title, from next to the section number to below the section number. I added the ipsum so you can see that the page number resets to 1 on every page, even though it should only reset at a new subsection.

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{article}      
\usepackage[headheight=110pt]{geometry}                     
\geometry{a4paper}                          
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\newcommand{\myparagraph}[1]{\paragraph{#1}\mbox{}\\}
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\usepackage{graphicx}               
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath, etoolbox}
\usepackage{multicol}               %to make columns
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}         %prevents hyphenation
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}     % prevents justified text
\usepackage{sectsty}

\setcounter{section}{1}
\numberwithin{page}{subsection}

\def\rescntr{\setcounter{page}{1}} % NEW CODE to make the page number reset to 1 at every subsection
\appto\subsection{\rescntr}

\let\stdsection\subsection
\renewcommand\subsection{\newpage\stdsection} % every subsection starts at a new page
\renewcommand\subsection{\clearpage\setcounter{page}{1}\stdsection}
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\thesubsection-\arabic{page}}

\subsectionfont{\scshape\MakeUppercase} % this doesn't work anymore due the new code \def\rescntr command
\subsubsectionfont{\scshape\MakeUppercase}
\paragraphfont{\scshape\MakeUppercase}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{Date: 01 AUG 2011\\Revision number: 1\\Page \thepage}
\chead{\parbox[b][17mm][c]{5cm}{\centering { Manual I\\ Something here\\  \rightmark}}}


\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}

\subsection{General}
\subsubsection{General Introduction}
\myparagraph{Introduction}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui.

\myparagraph{First}
Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc, quis gravida magna mi a libero. Fusce vulputate eleifend sapien. Vestibulum purus quam, scelerisque ut, mollis sed, nonummy id, metus. Nullam accumsan lorem in dui. Cras ultricies mi eu turpis hendrerit fringilla. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; In ac dui quis mi consectetuer lacinia.


\myparagraph{Second}
Nam pretium turpis et arcu. Duis arcu tortor, suscipit eget, imperdiet nec, imperdiet iaculis, ipsum. Sed aliquam ultrices mauris. Integer ante arcu, accumsan a, consectetuer eget, posuere ut, mauris. Praesent adipiscing. Phasellus ullamcorper ipsum rutrum nunc. Nunc nonummy metus. Vestibulum volutpat pretium libero. Cras id dui. Aenean ut eros et nisl sagittis vestibulum. Nullam nulla eros, ultricies sit amet, nonummy id, imperdiet feugiat, pede. Sed lectus. Donec mollis hendrerit risus. Phasellus nec sem in justo pellentesque facilisis. Etiam imperdiet imperdiet orci. Nunc nec neque. Phasellus leo dolor, tempus non, auctor et, hendrerit quis, nisi
\myparagraph{Third}
Curabitur ligula sapien, tincidunt non, euismod vitae, posuere imperdiet, leo. Maecenas malesuada. Praesent congue erat at massa. Sed cursus turpis vitae tortor. Donec posuere vulputate arcu. Phasellus accumsan cursus velit. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Sed aliquam, nisi quis porttitor congue, elit erat euismod orci, ac placerat dolor lectus quis orci. Phasellus consectetuer vestibulum elit. Aenean tellus metus, bibendum sed, posuere ac, mattis non, nunc. Vestibulum fringilla pede sit amet augue. In turpis. Pellentesque posuere. Praesent turpis.
\myparagraph{Fourth}
\myparagraph{Fifth}
\myparagraph{Sixtht}
\myparagraph{Seventh}
\subsection{Subsection 2}
\subsection{Next Subsection}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: why are you setting the page count to 1 in two places? `\def\rescntr{\setcounter{page}{1}} % NEW CODE to make the page number reset to 1 at every subsection
\appto\subsection{\rescntr}` doesn't look like it is doing much  useful and  `\renewcommand\subsection{\newpage\stdsection} % every subsection starts at a new page` does nothing as you redefine it again on the next line.  This should be enough `\renewcommand\subsection{\clearpage\setcounter{page}{1}\stdsection}`

Comment: I see your point. I removed the \def.. part, and only use the last \renewcommand. Unfortunately, the problem is not solved, since even though every page does get a new number, the page number resets to 0 at every subsection (and I want it to reset to 1).

Comment: oh you set it in _three_ places! delete `\numberwithin{page}{subsection}`  You just want one instance of `\setcounter{page}{1}` that;s all.

Comment: why do you have `\subsectionfont{\scshape\MakeUppercase`  ? `\scshape` does nothing if the text is uppercase. do you want uppercase or caps and small caps? You can't have both.

Comment: Thank you David! It works now! Bear in mind, I'm still a newb and I'm getting answers from different sources, so sometimes I have multiple commands for the same thing because they're still in there.
Considering your last comment, the subsection titles should be uppercase in the text only, but they need to remain as written in the header (i call upon \rightmark in the header)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell you want something like this (I added nothing but removed several commands)

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{article}      
\usepackage[headheight=110pt]{geometry}                     
\geometry{a4paper}                          
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\newcommand{\myparagraph}[1]{\paragraph{#1}\mbox{}\\}
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\usepackage{graphicx}               
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath, etoolbox}
\usepackage{multicol}               %to make columns
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}         %prevents hyphenation
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}     % prevents justified text
\usepackage{sectsty}


\let\stdsection\subsection
\renewcommand\subsection{\clearpage\setcounter{page}{1}\stdsection}
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\thesubsection-\arabic{page}}

\subsectionfont{MakeUppercase} % this doesn't work anymore due the new code \def\rescntr command
\subsubsectionfont{\MakeUppercase}
\paragraphfont{\MakeUppercase}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{Date: 01 AUG 2011\\Revision number: 1\\Page \thepage}
\chead{\parbox[b][17mm][c]{5cm}{\centering { Manual I\\ Something here\\  \rightmark}}}


\begin{document}

\section{zzz}
\begin{multicols}{2}

\subsection{General}
\subsubsection{General Introduction}
\myparagraph{Introduction}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui.

\myparagraph{First}
Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc, quis gravida magna mi a libero. Fusce vulputate eleifend sapien. Vestibulum purus quam, scelerisque ut, mollis sed, nonummy id, metus. Nullam accumsan lorem in dui. Cras ultricies mi eu turpis hendrerit fringilla. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; In ac dui quis mi consectetuer lacinia.


\myparagraph{Second}
Nam pretium turpis et arcu. Duis arcu tortor, suscipit eget, imperdiet nec, imperdiet iaculis, ipsum. Sed aliquam ultrices mauris. Integer ante arcu, accumsan a, consectetuer eget, posuere ut, mauris. Praesent adipiscing. Phasellus ullamcorper ipsum rutrum nunc. Nunc nonummy metus. Vestibulum volutpat pretium libero. Cras id dui. Aenean ut eros et nisl sagittis vestibulum. Nullam nulla eros, ultricies sit amet, nonummy id, imperdiet feugiat, pede. Sed lectus. Donec mollis hendrerit risus. Phasellus nec sem in justo pellentesque facilisis. Etiam imperdiet imperdiet orci. Nunc nec neque. Phasellus leo dolor, tempus non, auctor et, hendrerit quis, nisi
\myparagraph{Third}
Curabitur ligula sapien, tincidunt non, euismod vitae, posuere imperdiet, leo. Maecenas malesuada. Praesent congue erat at massa. Sed cursus turpis vitae tortor. Donec posuere vulputate arcu. Phasellus accumsan cursus velit. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Sed aliquam, nisi quis porttitor congue, elit erat euismod orci, ac placerat dolor lectus quis orci. Phasellus consectetuer vestibulum elit. Aenean tellus metus, bibendum sed, posuere ac, mattis non, nunc. Vestibulum fringilla pede sit amet augue. In turpis. Pellentesque posuere. Praesent turpis.
\myparagraph{Fourth}
\myparagraph{Fifth}
\myparagraph{Sixtht}
\myparagraph{Seventh}
\subsection{Subsection 2}
\subsection{Next Subsection}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```